# R for loop question: "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" when looping over dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to reformat a string variable as date in R for several datasets that contain the same variable. When I run my code on only one dataframe, it works, but when I try to iterate over several dataframes using a for loop, I receive the error: **Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.** Here is my code:

```
# dataframes are df1, df2, and df3, all containing the column "date" in character format
list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
for (i in seq_along(list)) {
  i$date <- as.Date(i$date, "%Y-%m-%d")
}
```

This results in the error mentioned above. I have tried with and without seq_along() and get the same error. When I run the following on only one dataframe, the code works:

```
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Can someone please suggest a fix? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`i` is an integer, not something you can `$`-index on, perhaps you meant `list[[i]]`?

BTW, naming a variable the same as a base (and very-frequently used) function is a really bad idea and bad practice. I first recommend renaming it:

```r
mylist <- list(df1, df2, df3)
for (i in seq_along(mylist)) {
  mylist[[i]]$date <- as.Date(mylist[[i]]$date, "%Y-%m-%d")
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `lapply` to apply a function to each element, and save it back into the original list.

```r
mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(L) {
  L$date <- as.Date(L$date, "%Y-%m-%d")
  L
})
```

One can shorten this a little (as reminded by @Onyambu) with

```r
mylist <- lapply(mylist, transform , date = as.Date(date,"%Y-%m-%d"))
```

If you're familiar with the tidyverse dialect, `transform` is the base R equivalent of `mutate`. (If not, then ignore this note :-)

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron

Comment: `lapply(myList, transform , date = as.Date(date,"%Y-%m-%d"))` should also do the trick

Comment: Absolutely ... I considered adding that but didn't want to introduce too much at once. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you both for the help. @r2evans, good point about naming a list "list". I actually called it "datalist", so I'm not sure why it copied that way.
Onyambu, your method worked, but I would also like to save over the original dataframes so that i have three separate dataframes with the reformatted column. Any insight on this? Thanks!